# Zabbix - triggering on text, displaying only part of the text

Tags: zabbix

I'm monitoring a web page that displays the status of a few hundred items. The page looks like this:
{"arrisId":"a000098","status":"Running","startTime":"2018-05-10T08:02:19.563Z"},{"arrisId":"a000101","status":"Running","startTime":"2018-05-10T08:02:19.892Z"},{"arrisId":"a000107","status":"Running","startTime":"2018-05-10T08:02:28.556Z"},...

What I want to do is trigger when 1 of the things is "Not Running", but I would like to display only the item that is not working and not the entire page. Hope that makes sense. I could use web.page.regexp and send a message that something is not running, but if I use web.page.get, is there a way to configure a trigger to display the not running and the 25 or so characters in front of that?
I hope this question makes sense.

Comment: I think what I want is an item like this, but I must be messing up the custom expression  web.page.regexp[ip,path,port,^(arrisId)?Not Running$]   what part of ^(arrisId)?Not Running$ do I have wrong?

Comment: Let's say that `http://..../status` returns the whole json page. Do you have an URL mapped to a single "arrisId", something like `http://..../status?id=a000101` which yealds a single object?

Comment: Yes, I can do that, but then I have to create like 300 of them. I came up with this 1 »  "arrisId":"a+[0-9.]+",+"status"+:+"Not Running" [Result is TRUE] and it works in the Regular expressions tester, but not when I use it in a trigger

Comment: You should do a low level discovery on the main status page to create the 300 items and relative triggers. For sure you'll have to write the script for the LLD rule. For the 300 items you can use the http agent check (zabbix 4.0 only) or a custom script.

Answer (score 0):

Your best course of action is to use [Low Level Discovery](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/3.4/manual/discovery/low_level_discovery).

Your LLD rule will run a script to ingest your main status page, then parse it and use the fields to create your items according to the "Item prototypes" you define.

The item prototype themselves will need a script as well to get their respective information (unless you are willing to use the Zabbix in beta)

I've done a simple setup, using mock json from [here](https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users):

**LLD Script**: will parse the mock json and convert it into a Zabbix LLD compliant format:

```
import requests
import json

jsonSource = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users"
lld = {}
data = []
lld['data'] = data

session = requests.Session()
response = session.get(jsonSource)

for jsonObject in response.json():
    data.append ( {
        '{#NAME}':  jsonObject['name'],
        '{#ID}':  jsonObject['id'],
        '{#URL}':  jsonSource + '/' + str(jsonObject['id'])
    } )
```

print json.dumps(lld)

**Item GET Script**: get a specific field of a specific item (will become obsolete with http agent item from Zabbix 4.0):

```
import requests
import json
import sys, argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-i', required=True, metavar='User ID')
parser.add_argument('-f', required=True, metavar='\"Requested JSON Field\"')
args = parser.parse_args()

jsonSource = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/" + args.i
session = requests.Session()
response = session.get(jsonSource)

print (response.json()[args.f])
```

Command line usage sample:

```
$ jsonLLD.py
{"data": [{"{#ID}": 1, "{#URL}": "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/1", "{#NAME}": "Leanne Graham"}, {"{#ID}": 2, "{#URL}": "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/2", "{#NAME}": "Ervin Howell"},
[cut]

$ jsonGet.py  -i 10 -f phone
024-648-3804
$ jsonGet.py  -i 10 -f name
Clementina DuBuque
```

Then you have to set it up into Zabbix:

- create a new template
- create a Discovery rule of "Zabbix agent" type and set it to run `system.run[/usr/bin/jsonLLD.py]` (mind the path!)
- create an item prototype for each json field you want to work on (ie: Item name: `{#NAME} telephone number`, Item key `system.run[/usr/bin/jsonGet.py  -i {#ID} -f phone]` )
- create trigger prototypes accordingly
- associate an host to the template

In your situation I'd use the Zabbix server itself as host, and install the scripts in its /usr/bin.
Watch the Zabbix Agent's log to see the discovery and item gathering process:

```
  1972:20180519:121849.052 Executing command '/usr/bin/jsonGet.py  -i 1 -f phone'
  1971:20180519:121850.054 Executing command '/usr/bin/jsonGet.py  -i 2 -f phone'
  1974:20180519:121851.055 Executing command '/usr/bin/jsonGet.py  -i 3 -f phone'
  1974:20180519:121852.073 Executing command '/usr/bin/jsonGet.py  -i 4 -f phone'
  1974:20180519:121853.076 Executing command '/usr/bin/jsonGet.py  -i 5 -f phone'
  1973:20180519:121854.077 Executing command '/usr/bin/jsonGet.py  -i 6 -f phone'
  1972:20180519:121855.079 Executing command '/usr/bin/jsonGet.py  -i 7 -f phone'

[cut]
```